# Bitcoin Pluggable Consensus with Algorand?

Tags: consensus

Algorand is an extremely promising consensus protocol -- Could Bitcoin be configured to use Algorand?

Answer (score 5):

No.

You can't change Bitcoin's consensus algorithm. If you do, and you don't convince literally everyone to do the same thing, you'll end up with a fork in the chain. At best, that means you won't see any new blocks anymore. At worst, you'll end up with two active chains, and a split currency.